Supabase linked tables - foreign_key_violation
I have created a “Users” table in Supabase public schema that I can use alongside the users table in “auth” schema, in order to capture more information (first name, last name).
I have linked the user id from the auth schema to the user id from the new table that I made and I created a workflow on register to add the additional information (first name, last name) into the new users table.
The problem is that even though both ID types are UUID, the workflow keeps crashing and in Supabase I get this message, saying that the column types don’t match, even though they are both UUID. I don’t know what to do here.
Screenshot 1
Screenshot 2
Screenshot 3
